# Ex 6.7 in Görtz and Wedhorn's AGI

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From *Algebraic Geometry I*, by Ulrich Görtz and Torsten Wedhon, p.165:

> **Exercise $\boldsymbol{6.7}$.** Let $k$ be a field, let $X$ be a $k$-scheme, and let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be closed subschemes of of $X$ and let $Y_1\cap Y_2$ be their schematic intersection. Let $x\in(Y_1\cap Y_2)(k)$ be a $k$-valued point and assume that $X$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$ are smooth in $x$ over $k$ of relative dimension $d$, $d-c_1$, and $d-c_2$, respectively. Show that the following assertions are equivalent.
>
> $\ (i)$ $Y_1\cap Y_2$ is smooth at $x$ of relative dimension $d-(c_1+c_2)$.
> $(ii)$ $T_xY_1+T_xY_2=T_xX$.

It's easy for affine algebraic variety. However, I have no idea on how to relate tangent spaces with smoothness in general schemes.
Could anyone please help me to give a proof?

Comment: And what about the other author?

Comment: @johnw. Hi, different author gives different definition for smoothness. I will appreciate it even if you give a proof based on other authors. And it also may improve my understanding of smoothness.

Comment: Dear Fang, I think the point of @johnw. 's comment was that there are two authors of the book you link to (Wedhorn as well as Görtz), but your title only mentions one of them.  Regards,

Comment: You shouldn't post the electronic file of the whole book.

Comment: @MattE Oh, got it. I have added the other author's name..

Comment: @Cantlog I am sorry. Got it. Thank you for reminding me of that.

Comment: @Fang: I think the statement is not completely correct because (i) is a global property, while (ii) only concerns what happens around $x$. One should replace (i) by $Y_1\cap Y_2$ smooth at $x$ and of dimension $d-c_1-c_2$ at $x$. Then the question is purely local and one can suppose $X$ is affine.

Comment: @Cantlog Thanks very much. I have modified this question.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by general schemes ? Is $x$ still a rational point over $k$ ?